# Unaccounted time in workitem report

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

There is an 18 second gap between the loading of the last dll and the start of the plug in script, which seemingly starts at "Press Enter to continue".

Why does it take 18 seconds for my script to start? What is occuring during that time?

Is there a way to reduce this duration?

I have tried reducing the number of dlls (removing AECC Hydrology and other dll for example), however the 18 second gap remains.

Extract from work item report:

```
[09/21/2022 19:22:10] Loading AECC Point Cloud...
[09/21/2022 19:22:10] Loading AECC Hydrology...
[09/21/2022 19:22:28] Press ENTER to continue:
[09/21/2022 19:22:28] Command:
[09/21/2022 19:22:29] Command:
[09/21/2022 19:22:29] Command:
[09/21/2022 19:22:29] Command: UpdateModel
```

Comment: Which Design automation engine is this for (ACAD, Revit, Inventor, 3ds Max)? Can you provide a workitem id?

Comment: engine: ACAD 2023, id: "8f93488c40bf4df086c501cabc2deb12".

Comment: @BEDMED, we are investigating this, from the log it appears that you are opening a C3D drawing, can you share the drawing with us ? forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala I sent you the model. Thank you for your help.